# What to do after clonezilla partition install on new machine? refresh grub? fstab? create swap?

Tags: grub2, partitioning, clonezilla

Amazingly, somehow, I... a noob.. successfully restored a cloned linux partition from my old laptop into my new one (and didn't lose windows in the process).  Then successfully got to grub2 rescue mode and booted into my cloned ubuntu partition.

Feeling pretty BA about right now..

Anyways,

1. How to refresh grub to reflect changes to partitions and OS's? (this might already be done) (**edit|** There are some specific problems with grub.  I will post a new question and put link here.  Here's the link: [grub help](https://askubuntu.com/questions/659170/help-with-grub-errors-after-installing-cloned-partition-on-new-laptop))
2. Do I need to update anything else?  Such as fstab? (not sure what that is but I know it has to do with disks)
3. I did not clone my swap partition when I cloned ubuntu with clonezilla in the old machine.  Should I create a new swap partition?  how?
4. Anything else?

Thank you.